# Backup full system image to amazon s3

Tags: server, backup, disk-image

The normal way i get used to take full image backup for my server to external device by:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/my_device/disk_sda.img
```

Or to another external server:

```
ssh root@111.111.111.111 "dd if=/dev/sda " | dd of=/home/disk_sda.img
```

Sometimes i don't have local space/ drive size that suits the images, so i want to take the full backup and upload it to S3 on amazone directly without external device/ server, is that possible?